# Prove that $\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{I}}^G \cong \mathbb{C}[G]$

Tags: representation-theory

> Prove that $\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{I}}^G \cong \mathbb{C}[G]$.

Apparently: $$\langle \mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{I}}^G \mathbb{I}, \chi  \rangle_G \overset{Frob.Rep.}= \langle \mathbb{I}, \mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi  \rangle_I= \dim \chi \tag1$$

but I cannot see how the second inequality works?

So then apparently this means that $\displaystyle \mathbb{C}[G]=\bigoplus_{V_i \ irreducible}V_i^{\dim V_i}\tag2$

equally I cannot see how this is a consequence of $(1)$.

My inner product of characters is $\displaystyle \langle \chi, \psi \rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g)\overline{\psi(g)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is just over a single element:
$$\langle\mathbb I, \mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi\rangle_{\{I\}} = \frac{1}{1}\sum_{g \in \{I\}}\chi(g)\overline{\mathbb I(g)} = \chi(I)\overline{\mathbb I(I)} = \dim\chi\cdot\dim\mathbb I = \dim\chi$$

Now observe that characters form an inner product space with an orthogonal basis.  Consequently, characters are defined by their inner product with other characters.  You've shown that the inner product of $\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb I}^G$ with $\chi$ equals the inner product of $\mathbb C[G]$ with $\chi$ for *all* $\chi$, hence the characters of $\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb I}^G$ and $\mathbb C[G]$ are equal.  Hence $\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb I}^G$ and $\mathbb C[G]$ are isomorphic.

Comment: How is it possible that $\mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi = \mathbb{I} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{I}$

Comment: @1234: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Apparently in my notes $\mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi = \mathbb{I} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{I}$, this would surely provide an easy way of solving this. I just wondered why/how the equality holds

Comment: Both $\mathbb I \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb I$ and $\mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi$ are vector spaces with the trivial action of the trivial group.

Comment: I dont see why they equal. Also $\mathbb{I}$ isnt a subgroup so what it means to restrict to it

Comment: They are equal because they are vector spaces of the same dimension with the same action.  And you're not restricting to $\mathbb I$, you're restricting to $\{I\}$ which is a subgroup.